If the requests are from the same IP and Port, will the AWS NLB redirect them to the same target?
I'm using AWS Network Load Balancer as a k8s service for my deployment. The reason I use NLB instead of ALB is that I need a static host to expose my service inside my Elastic Kubernetes Service(EKS). The NLB I deployed uses such yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: ip
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
  name: my-nlb
  namespace: my-ns
spec:
  ports:
    - name: webport
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
    selector:
      app: my-app
    type: LoadBalancer

The problem is that, when I made a deployment with 2 replicas, and checked they are selected by NLB. I do some test like:
ab -c 100 -n 3000 http://AWS-NLB-Hostname

It seems that all the requests went to the same pod.
I know NLB is using hash for load balancing, does it mean it will load all requests from the same IP to the same target? If so (or not), what should I do to fix that?
Because my service is stateless, I hope that all the requests are balanced across all the pods.

my guess is that this is working as expected and that you have stickiness for sessions enabled on the alb or that the aws-load-balancer-controller defaults to session stickiness.
apparently you can verify this with ab by using a forced ip

